# How can I contact blizzard support without login to my account

Tags: battle.net

I tried to login to Diablo 3 and get a message stating wrong password.

I reset my password, but when I enter the password I remember, it says that I can't use the same password with existing password.

Then I change password to a different password anyway.

I tried to login again and the authenticator keeps giving the wrong number.

So I can't login to the battle net and then I can't ask support because only those who login can submit ticket.

In short, trying to login to my account gives error message authenticator code is wrong.
Trying to login to Diablo 3 gives error message wrong password.

Comment: Mobile Authenticator?  Close the app and re-open it.  I had that happen to me.

Comment: Thanks everyone. All I need to do is to "sync" that mobile authenticator and everything back to normal.

Comment: Blizzard's support stinks. And this page getting 55k views shows that blizzard really need to improve its support system.

Answer (score 5):

View their contact page [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120830172531/http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/contact)

You can call them at this number according to this site.

```
United States/Canada   1-800-592-5499
```

Comment: That's the same number for both countries.  I wonder why the site even bothers putting them on separate lines.

Comment: I wondered the same thing. They might as well just put it like my post, and remove the "United States / Canada" lines, and just keep it North America.

Comment: @leety updated to show that

Comment: @Halfwarr I didn't mean you, I meant Bnet / Blizzard. :p

Comment: @leety I am Blizzard...er.. Batman... er.. Bruce Wayne, well I'm the hero that Gotham needs, well ok its kinda complicated.

Comment: @Halfwarr, No email?

Answer (score 2):

**Mobile Authenticator**

---

Like fbueckert said in their comment, if it's a Mobile Authenticator, try closing and re-opening it.

Another possibility is that your Serial has got out of Sync. Which this means you will most definitely have to get in contact with customer support.

**Suggestion**

---

Since you can't log into your account, I'd recommend giving them a call. I've had both good and bad experiences while calling Battle.net/Blizzard.

> **North America**
>
> Hours: 7 am - 8 pm Pacific Time, 7 days a week
>
> 1-800-592-5499

[Here is the full list of contact information](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/contact)