# Is it possible to remove a battle.net authenticator without a government issued ID?

Tags: battle.net

I do not have a "government issued ID" which is something Blizzard's website says I need in order to remove my Battle.net authenticator.  Are there are any other methods I can use to get the authenticator off my account without actually having the authenticator?

I thought I had made a note of the authenticator serial number somewhere in order to replicate it in the event I ever had to reset my iPhone back to factory settings, but I don't appear to have done so, which means I cannot log into my Diablo 3 account.

Comment: I feel for you.  I had the same problem.  Happily, getting an actual person on the phone works so much better than emailing back and forth!

Comment: Hi, purplerain, and welcome to Arqade!  Just a quick word of advice to help you out in the future: Think of what the actual problem is that you're facing, not what is blocking you.  In this case, the problem isn't that you can't remove an authenticator from your account, but rather that you are unable to log into your account because you no longer have a valid authenticator.  Here it doesn't make a lot of difference (other than it's valuable information to know up front), but down the road, it could make a huge impact on the type of answers you receive to other questions.

Comment: You used to be able to live chat with them but now you can't even do that if you have one attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can't log into your account, and it looks like you are trying to avoid using a "government issued ID", I'd recommend giving them a call. I've had both good and bad experiences while calling Battle.net/Blizzard.

> **North America**
>
> Hours: 10 am - 6 pm Pacific Time, 7 days a week
>
> 1-800-592-5499

[Here is the full list of contact information](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/contact)

This was taken from [my answer in another post on arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85240/how-can-i-contact-blizzard-support-without-login-to-my-account).

Do note that sometimes they may ask for some personal information.

Comment: im not avoiding, i dont have a drivers license or passport so i dont have one to use in the first place

Comment: i will give them a call ty